# Can I change the indenting style used when saving a DataSet to xml

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I'd like to use tabs, or at least more than 2 spaces per indent level.  IIRC there are options available to adjust this when using serialization to write a class out; but I don't see any way to adjust the behavior when calling `MyDataSet.WriteXml(filename)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `XmlTextWriter` if you want to influence the layout of your XML being saved:

```
XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(filename, Encoding.UTF8);
xtw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xtw.Indentation = 4;
xtw.IndentChar = '\t';
```

and then write out your data set using that `XmlTextWriter`:

```
MyDataSet.WriteXml(xtw);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that produce an indentation of 4 tab characters? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the overloads that accepts an `XmlWriter`, and pass in an `XmlWriter` configured with an `XmlWriterSettings` object that has the options you want.

---

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                             {
                                 Indent = true, 
                                 IndentChars = "\t"
                             };
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("file.xml", settings))
{
    ds.WriteXml(writer);
}
```